# Change of coordinates in an integral depending on the limits of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I hope this is a useful question, since I did not find any equivalent thread.

Assume you have an integral that depends on one limit of integration such as

$\int_a^b \phi(\tau, b) d\tau$

Now, I would like to perform a change of coordinates such as $\tau = f(\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is the new integration variable. Assume that there is a relation between $d\tau$ and $d\sigma$: $d\tau = f' \; d\sigma=v \;d\sigma$. My question is the limit of integration $b$ in the $\phi$ function has to transformed or not in the new variable coordinates. In other words, which one of the following expression is right?

1. $\int_{f^-1(a)}^{f^-1(b)} \phi(f(\sigma), b) v d\sigma$
2. $\int_{f^-1(a)}^{f^-1(b)} \phi(f(\sigma), f^-1(b)) v d\sigma$

I personally think that the first expression is the right one, but I want to be sure about that.

Thank you for any reply and suggestion. Best regards,

Neostek

Answer (score 1):

Well, $b$ is just a constant here, not a variable of integration or anything like that, so your first expression is right. An easy way to see this is replacing $b$ by a number, say $1$, then if we make the substitution $\tau=f(\sigma)$, we would simply have
$$\int_a^1 \phi(\tau,1)\ d\tau=\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(1)} \phi(f(\sigma),1)f'(\sigma)\ d\sigma$$
Also, be careful with using $f^{-1}$, since both $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ may be the same value, and then you have to separate the integral into parts when $\sigma$ is increasing and decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

At this point, I'm curious. What if the limit of integration b
is a function or a variable of integration? As example b(σ)

Thank you,

Neostek

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense to have the bounds be a function of $\sigma$, the variable of integration, as the bounds determine what $\sigma$ we integrate over. You could still have the bounds be a function of some other variable, but not of the variable of integration.

Comment: Yes, maybe I posted wrongly. What if $b$ is not a constant?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should explain what I mean by constant: I mean it is constant with respect to $\tau$, the variable of integration, so in terms of evaluating the integral, we can treat it as a constant. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, I got your point. Yes, I guess that if $b(\tau)$,then I have to transform it as

$\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b(f(\sigma)))} \phi(f(\sigma),f^{-1}(b(f(\sigma)))) d\sigma$

Is that correct? Thank you

Neostek

Comment: Not quite, it still does not make sense to have the variable of integration in the bounds. Think of how $\int_0^x x^2 dx$ might be confusing.